# Python - Load multiple excel files with multiple sheets in it with specific columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

**I have a problem scenario where I need to load excel files using Python**

- Load multiple excel files from a folder - **Done**
- Each excel file has multiple sheets - **Done**
- Need to load only required columns (*'Receive Date','Process Date','Process Number','Task Name','Series','Office','Department','Unit Manager','AM'*), other columns needs to be ignored/dropped and no error should be raised if the above columns does not exist in some sheets.
- Load all the data into single data frame

**------ Code -------**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

def getfilepath():
    path = 'C:/Users/Tracking Logs/'
    files=(os.listdir(path))
    allfiles = glob.glob(path+"*.xlsx")

def getdatafromexcel():
    for file in allfiles:
        rawdf = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=None,na_values='null',keep_default_na=False,dtype=object,date_parser=True)
        cols=('Receive Date','Process Date','Process Number','Task Name','Series','Office','Department','Unit Manager','AM/AA/PC')
        display(df)
    
getfilepath()
getdatafromexcel()
```

Comment: you can pass `cols` into your `pd.read_excel` function call for example `pd.read_excel(...,usecols=cols)` note `cols` should be a list and not a tuple see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Thank you @Umar.H, this helped as I was using tuple, now after using Tuple I get error saying few columns do not match. There are scenarios where all the sheets will not have these columns and hence I need to ignore that particular sheet from loading.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure it out :) you can use a blanket `try` `except` with the error that is displayed when a column doesn't match.

Comment: Yes @Umar.H, let me take it forward from here.

Comment: Thank @Umar.H, I have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from IPython.display import HTML,display
from openpyxl import load_workbook    

path = 'C:/Users/Tracking Logs/'
cols = ['Receive Date','Process Date','Task Name','Series','Office','Department','Unit Manager','AM/AA/PC']

def getfilepath(path):    
    files=(os.listdir(path))
    allfiles = glob.glob(path+"*.xlsx") 
    #print('Allfiles: ',allfiles)
    return allfiles

def getdatafromexcel(cols,allfiles):   
    for i in range(len(allfiles)): 
        print('\nCounter: ',i,' \nFilenames: ',allfiles[i])         
        wb = load_workbook(allfiles[i],read_only=True)                     
        for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:    
            print('Sheetname: ',sheetname)
            try:                
                df = pd.read_excel(allfiles[i],sheet_name=sheetname,na_values='null',usecols=cols,
                           keep_default_na=False,dtype=object)
                Indexnames = df[(df["Task Name"] == '') & (df["Series"] == '') & (df["Office"] == '')].index
                df.drop(Indexnames,inplace=True)
                display(df)
                fulldf=fulldf.append(df,ignore_index=True)             
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)                                          
            finally:   
                print('this executed')
                wb.close()                       
    display(fulldf)
    
allfiles = getfilepath(path)
getdatafromexcel(cols,allfiles)
```

Comment: don't forget to accept your own answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

**One can use pd.ExcelFile and pd.read_excel to get the required results.**

```
def getdatafromexcel():
    for file in allfiles:
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        res = len(xl.sheet_names)

    
    if res>1:
        for i in range(1, res+1):
            df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name= '%d' %i)
            # Do selection, preprocessing what you want here

            if i == 1:
                df.to_csv(<your_path> + '1.csv')
                df_1 = pd.read_csv(<your_path> +  '1.csv')

            if i > 1:
                df_1 = pd.concat([df_1, df])

    else: 
        df_1 = pd.read_excel(file)
        # Do selection, preprocessing what you what here
        df_1.to_csv(<your_path> + '.csv', index= False)
```

Comment: Thanks @Pawan Jain for your inputs and time, I tried couple of things and it is fixed now.