# Organize flow data from multiple excel sheets into one excel by iterrating through each column

Tags: python, excel

I have the paths to each excel file in 'files'(using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67597943/16716479)).
And then, I was trying to use a for loop to iterate through each file and gather flow data and combine it into new matrix 'val' by adding it to a new column each time. 'Flow' is also the column name in the excel so I use that on line 5 to call the column I want.

For example,

Excel 1

Flow data

1

2

Excel 2:

Flow data

3

4

val matrix should have

Excel 1  Excel 2

1         3

2         4

I keep getting this error however.

could not broadcast input array from shape (105408,1) into shape (105408,)

Seems like a common error but I haven't been able to solve it from similar question on here.

```
val = np.zeros((105408, 50), int)
for x in range (len(files)+1):
    dt = pd.read_csv(files[x])
    flow_data = dt[['Flow']]
    val[:,x] = flow_data
    #print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into an issue due to the extra pair of brackets surrounding `'Flow'`, removing should function as you intended. `dt[['Flow']] --> dt['Flow']`

Using a dataframe might be a better approach to aggregate results though, a `numpy.ndarray` will throw an error if `len(files)` turns out to be larger than the preset array width (50 in this case). A df will be more flexible for varying file counts/rows. Which seems to be the case given you are using len(files) and not a specific file count.

Working example (using `pd.DataFrame`):

```
aggregate_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range (len(files)+1):
    dt = pd.read_csv(files[x])
    flow_data = dt['Flow']
    aggregate_df.loc[:, x] = flow_data  # using a df to aggregate results
    # print(aggregate_df)
```

Comment: Dataframe runs much better. Thanks!